# Can't Return When Looping

Tags: php, loops

Why I can't return while looping in function? Why I just got 1 result like without looping? Here is my code:

```
function search($get){
    $i=0;

    //print_r($get);
    foreach($get->itemlist as $song){
        $i++;
        $ch = curl_init('');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'wmid=14997771; user_type=2; country=id; session_key=96870dd03ab9280c905566cad439c904;');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36');
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = str_replace('MusicInfoCallback(', '', $json);
        $json = str_replace(')', '', $json);
        $json = json_decode($json);
        $songurl = $json->mp3Url;
        //print_r($json);
        return array($i => array("song" => $json->msong,
                                 "singer" => $json->msinger,
                                 "url" => $song->songid));
    }
}
print_r(search("key"));
```

any alternative?

Comment: You are returning your array inside your `foreach` loop. Try assigning a new variable outside your `foreach` then set its data inside your loop then return the assigned variable outside your `foreach`

Comment: Also, it is not recommended that you perform `str_replace()` on json data.  This can unintentionally mangle your data.  It is better to `json_decode()` first then deal with keys and values after.  If this string manipulation is necessary before decoding, then use a different function/process.

Answer (score 1):

Untested Code:

```
function search($get){
    foreach($get->itemlist as $song){
        $ch = curl_init('');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'wmid=14997771; user_type=2; country=id; session_key=96870dd03ab9280c905566cad439c904;');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36');
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode(substr($json,18,-1),true);
        $results[]=['songurl'=>$json['mp3Url'],
                    'song'=>$json['msong'],
                    'singer'=>$json['msinger'],
                    'url'=>$song->songid
                   ];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I don't have any sample data to verify my code with.  I am making an assumption that `'MusicInfoCallback(` and `)` are the start and end of the curl string.  I recommend packing all data into an (automatically) indexed array.

`$songurl` was also "trapped" within the scope of the function.

Comment: Just a typo I have seen. return $result; should be return $results; OPs don't always see this :)